# Why Does A Fluid Simulation Not Completely Fill an Area?

Tags: fluid-simulation

[image]

As seen in the image below in a fluid simulation an object marked with collision is not completely filled, how would I fix this?

Comment: Hello and welcome! Check all the physics properties, I believe there is a setting for the mesh collision margin or similar, set it to zero.

Comment: if you provide the blend file so we can see the important settings, we can tell you ;)

Comment: Yeah I see it, thanks! :)